# How magnitude affects angular diameter/resolution

Tags: astronomy

Let's say you look at two relatively dim stars in the night sky. They are close to each other, but they are far away enough that you can distinguish one from the other. But what if one of them is much brighter than the other, or both of them are very bright, and they look like one star due to it (though you should normally distinguish them as separate objects)? I read about angular resolution, but I never saw any relation of it to magnitude.

In my fictional world, I have two planets with big moons that are separated enough from each other to be visible as separate objects (angular diameter is larger than the angular resolution of the human eye). But both planets have pretty high apparent magnitudes, so I am not sure if they outshine their moons or not. Ganymede should be distinguished as a separate object from Jupiter, but Jupiter is so bright you need a telescope or binoculars to see them as separate objects.

Comment: Some very few people with exceptionally good visual acuity *can* see some of the Galilean satellites of Jupiter without instruments, at least Ganymede and sometimes also Callisto. [Here is an astronomer's report](https://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1898PA......6..257S) from 1898. If your planet is sufficiently far so that it appears almost star-like, the difference in apparent magnitude between the planet and a satellite will likely be too great to allow casual naked eye observation of the satellite.

Comment: First planet have maximum apparent magnitude -8,62, first moon have apparent magnitude -3,1, they are both separeted by 0,463° angular diameter. Second planet have maximum apparent magnitude -6,08, second moon have apparent magnitude -2,95, they are both separeted by 1,332° angular diameter. But I am more interested in some calculations or charts which can help to tell if moon can be distinguished from planet or not.

Comment: Oh, they are separated by 27′ and 1° 20′ respectively? That's *huge*. (To understand how huge that angular distance is, consider that the *full moon* is about 30′. And it is *large*, isn't it?) The celestial bodies can absolutely be seen with the naked eye by an average observer, even from a light-polluted city. The celestial bodies with apparent magnitudes of −9 and −6 will be visible in daylight, and even those with apparent magnitudes of −3 may be visible in daylight if not  close to the sun.

Comment: Yes. I calculated values from δ = 2*arcsin(r/D), (δ = angular diameter, r = distance between objects, D = distance from observer). Home planet semi-major axis is 0,574 AU, first planet have SMA 0,399 AU, second planet 0,812 AU. First moon's SMA around planet is 105 900 km, second moon's SMA around planet is 414 320 km.